# input not aligning with with element under it

Tags: html, css

My input isnt alignin properly with the element under it, the accordion. I want the input to align horizontally with the accordion as the textt to the left does, Tried around diffrent things, but did more harm then good.

```js
//Accordion-----------------------------------------------
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".accordion-desc").fadeOut(0);
    $(".accordion").click(function () {
        $(".accordion-desc").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
        $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
    });
});

$(".accordion").click(function () {
    $(".accordion").not(this).find(".rotate").removeClass("down");
    $(this).find(".rotate").toggleClass("down");
});
//-----------------------------------------------------------
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

header {
    background-color: #2cc185;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2em 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
    background-color: #2cc185;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #239768;
    color: #fff;
}

button:focus {
    background-color: #239768;
    color: #fff;
}

.accordion {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #f1f4f3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f4f3;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #74777b;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/*Rotation-------------------------------------*/
.accordion .fa {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
.rotate {
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

    .rotate.down {
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
/*------------------------------------------*/
.link {

    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.accordion h4 {
    position: relative;
     /* top: 0.8em; */
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    float: left;
}

.accordion a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: #74777b;
    padding: 1em 1em 2.5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2cc185;
    background-color: #e7ecea;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.accordion-desc {
    background-color: #f1f4f3;
    color: #74777b;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 20px 15px;
}
@media (min-width:480px) {

    .container { max-width: 80%; }
}
@media (min-width:768px) {

    .container { max-width: 1000px; }
}
.accordion-desc p {
    word-break: break-all;
}

.accordion .status {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 20%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.heading {
    margin: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.heading h2 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin:auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.heading .searcheBar {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



    <div class="container">
        
        <div class ="heading">
            <h2>All projekt</h2>
                <input class="searcheBar form-control" type="text"/>
        </div>

                <div class="accordion">
                    <a href="#">
                        <h4>@item.Title</h4>
                        <h4 class="status">@Resource.AccordionStatus</h4>
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-desc">
                    <h3>@Resource.AccordionProjectLead</h3>
                    <h4>Kay Wiberg</h4>
                    <h3>@Resource.AccordionDescription</h3>
                    <p>
                    @item.Description
                    <p>
                    <div class="link">
                        <a href="@item.Url">@Resource.AccordionGoTo</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change :**

```
.heading {
    margin:10px;
    //more code...
}
```

**To:**

```
.heading {
    margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    //More code...
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

header {
    background-color: #2cc185;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2em 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
    background-color: #2cc185;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #239768;
    color: #fff;
}

button:focus {
    background-color: #239768;
    color: #fff;
}

.accordion {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #f1f4f3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f4f3;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #74777b;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/*Rotation-------------------------------------*/
.accordion .fa {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
.rotate {
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.rotate.down {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
/*------------------------------------------*/
.link {

    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.accordion h4 {
    position: relative;
     /* top: 0.8em; */
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    float: left;
}

.accordion a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: #74777b;
    padding: 1em 1em 2.5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2cc185;
    background-color: #e7ecea;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.accordion-desc {
    background-color: #f1f4f3;
    color: #74777b;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 20px 15px;
}
@media (min-width:480px) {

    .container { max-width: 80%; }
}
@media (min-width:768px) {

    .container { max-width: 1000px; }
}
.accordion-desc p {
    word-break: break-all;
}

.accordion .status {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 20%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.heading {
    margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.heading h2 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin:auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.heading .searcheBar {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">    
  <div class ="heading">
    <h2>All projekt</h2>
    <input class="searcheBar form-control" type="text"/>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion">
    <a href="#">
      <h4>@item.Title</h4>
      <h4 class="status">@Resource.AccordionStatus</h4>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-desc">
    <h3>@Resource.AccordionProjectLead</h3>
    <h4>Kay Wiberg</h4>
    <h3>@Resource.AccordionDescription</h3>
    <p>@item.Description</p>
    <div class="link">
      <a href="@item.Url">@Resource.AccordionGoTo</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option #1**
Adjusting margin:
`.heading {margin: 10px auto;}`

```js
//Accordion-----------------------------------------------
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accordion-desc").fadeOut(0);
  $(".accordion").click(function() {
    $(".accordion-desc").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
    $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
  });
});

$(".accordion").click(function() {
  $(".accordion").not(this).find(".rotate").removeClass("down");
  $(this).find(".rotate").toggleClass("down");
});
//-----------------------------------------------------------
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color: #2cc185;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2em 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
  background-color: #2cc185;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #239768;
  color: #fff;
}

button:focus {
  background-color: #239768;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #f1f4f3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f4f3;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #74777b;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/*Rotation-------------------------------------*/

.accordion .fa {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.rotate {
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.rotate.down {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}


/*------------------------------------------*/

.link {
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.accordion h4 {
  position: relative;
  /* top: 0.8em; */
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  float: left;
}

.accordion a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: #74777b;
  padding: 1em 1em 2.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2cc185;
  background-color: #e7ecea;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.accordion-desc {
  background-color: #f1f4f3;
  color: #74777b;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 20px 15px;
}

@media (min-width:480px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 80%;
  }
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1000px;
  }
}

.accordion-desc p {
  word-break: break-all;
}

.accordion .status {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: 20%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.heading {
  margin: 10px auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.heading h2 {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.heading .searcheBar {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Adjusting Margin</h1>

<div class="container">

  <div class="heading">
    <h2>All projekt</h2>
    <input class="searcheBar form-control" type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="accordion">
    <a href="#">
      <h4>@item.Title</h4>
      <h4 class="status">@Resource.AccordionStatus</h4>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-desc">
    <h3>@Resource.AccordionProjectLead</h3>
    <h4>Kay Wiberg</h4>
    <h3>@Resource.AccordionDescription</h3>
    <p>
      @item.Description
      <p>
        <div class="link">
          <a href="@item.Url">@Resource.AccordionGoTo</a>
        </div>
  </div>
```

**Option #2**
Deferring to padding:
`.heading {padding: 10px; box-sizing: border-box;}`

```js
//Accordion-----------------------------------------------
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accordion-desc").fadeOut(0);
  $(".accordion").click(function() {
    $(".accordion-desc").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
    $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
  });
});

$(".accordion").click(function() {
  $(".accordion").not(this).find(".rotate").removeClass("down");
  $(this).find(".rotate").toggleClass("down");
});
//-----------------------------------------------------------
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color: #2cc185;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2em 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
  background-color: #2cc185;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #239768;
  color: #fff;
}

button:focus {
  background-color: #239768;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #f1f4f3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f4f3;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #74777b;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/*Rotation-------------------------------------*/

.accordion .fa {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.rotate {
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.rotate.down {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}


/*------------------------------------------*/

.link {
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.accordion h4 {
  position: relative;
  /* top: 0.8em; */
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  float: left;
}

.accordion a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: #74777b;
  padding: 1em 1em 2.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2cc185;
  background-color: #e7ecea;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.accordion-desc {
  background-color: #f1f4f3;
  color: #74777b;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 20px 15px;
}

@media (min-width:480px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 80%;
  }
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1000px;
  }
}

.accordion-desc p {
  word-break: break-all;
}

.accordion .status {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: 20%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.heading {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.heading h2 {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.heading .searcheBar {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Deferring to Padding</h1>

<div class="container">

  <div class="heading">
    <h2>All projekt</h2>
    <input class="searcheBar form-control" type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="accordion">
    <a href="#">
      <h4>@item.Title</h4>
      <h4 class="status">@Resource.AccordionStatus</h4>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-desc">
    <h3>@Resource.AccordionProjectLead</h3>
    <h4>Kay Wiberg</h4>
    <h3>@Resource.AccordionDescription</h3>
    <p>
      @item.Description
      <p>
        <div class="link">
          <a href="@item.Url">@Resource.AccordionGoTo</a>
        </div>
  </div>
```